# WhatsApp font for emoticons (unicode, windows)

Tags: windows, unicode, fonts, emoticons

does anybody know how to render these emoticons in Windows given the unicode charcode?

It looks like this icons or font are native to apple (as sayed [here](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode#note1)) but I don't know which one I can choose to render these glyphs in Windows

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If whatever you're using to display your text is working correctly *and* the user has a suitable font installed, then you don't need to do anything. Font substitution will take care of that and choose a font that contains glyphs for those characters.

Windows since 8.1 ships with *Segoe UI Emoji*, however, if you absolutely need a font to specify explicitly.